# How to Add a Menu to a Telegram Bot Using Telethon Library

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, telethon

I have created a simple telegram bot that will take an input from a user and perform some operations and return the result to the user.

However, I want to add a menu where based on the menu option will call a specific function and return the result to the user. Each operation takes from 0 to 60 seconds and the bot is used by more than one user.

I have a few concern. First, how to make sure that the bot will store the entered value before the menu choice. Second, since the operation takes *N* seconds, how can I make sure that the each user will get its searched value instead of getting the result of another user?
Here is my code so far:

```
!/usr/bin/env python3.8
api_id = 12345
api_hash = 'XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
bot_token = 'XXXXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
############################### Bot ############################################
from telethon.sync import TelegramClient, events,Button
from telethon import functions, types
from telegram import InlineKeyboardButton, InlineKeyboardMarkup
def first_function(value):
    #DO SOME OPERATION
    return


def second_function(value):
    #DO SOME OPERATION
    return



bot = TelegramClient('bot', api_id, api_hash).start(bot_token=bot_token)
with bot:   
    @bot.on(events.NewMessage)
    async def handler(event):    
        value=event.message.message
        sender_id=event.message.peer_id.user_id
        username = await bot.get_entity(sender_id)
        #if menu option is 1
            # first_function(value)
        #else menu option is 2
        #second_function(value)

        await bot.send_message(username, value)        
    bot.run_until_disconnected()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add a menu to your Telegram bot.
Here is add a menu code:

```
menu_keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup([[
        InlineKeyboardButton("Option 1", callback_data='1'),
        InlineKeyboardButton("Option 2", callback_data='2')
    ]])
```

Make a callback:

```
async def callback_query_handler(event):
    callback_query = event.data
    if callback_query == '1':
        await first_function(value)
    elif callback_query == '2':
        await second_function(value)
```

Function send_message() write:

```
await bot.send_message(username, "Please select an option from the menu:", reply_markup=menu_keyboard)
```

Two functions add in your code:

```
def first_function(value):
    #DO SOME OPERATION
    return


def second_function(value):
    #DO SOME OPERATION
    return



bot = TelegramClient('bot', api_id, api_hash).start(bot_token=bot_token)
with bot:   
    @bot.on(events.NewMessage)
    async def handler(event):    
        value=event.message.message
        sender_id=event.message.peer_id.user_id
        username = await bot.get_entity(sender_id)
        menu_keyboard = InlineKeyboardMarkup(
            [[InlineKeyboardButton("Option 1", callback_data='1'),
              InlineKeyboardButton("Option 2", callback_data='2')]]
        )
        await bot.send_message(username, "Please select an option from the menu:", reply_markup=menu_keyboard)
        @bot.on(events.CallbackQuery)
        async def callback_query_handler(event):
            callback_query = event.data
            if callback_query == '1':
                await first_function(value)
            elif callback_query == '2':
                await second_function(value)
    bot.run_until_disconnected()
```

Comment: Your solution gives me this error "TypeError: send_message() got an unexpected keyword argument 'reply_markup'"

Comment: I have implemented your solution, but it calls the previous inputs too incrementally. and when I indent out the callback_query_handler. it won't get the username nor the message @sjstb99

Comment: What are you talking about? Don't make a prediction about the question.

Answer (score 1):

you should checkout the documentation [here](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/custom.html#telethon.tl.custom.button.Button.inline)

In the documentation, you can also refer examples.
example you should look for is [here](https://docs.telethon.dev/en/stable/modules/client.html#telethon.client.messages.MessageMethods.send_message).

Short example of adding buttons :

```
from telethon import Button
btns = [[Button.inline(“option 1”, data=“option1”), Button.inline(“Option 2”, data=“option2”)]
await client.send_message(…, buttons=btns)
```

Comment: I understand that part, but how to add it within the event handler?

Comment: You can still use the `bot` client instance from the handler. You can also use `await event.respond(..., buttons=btns)` from the handler.